# Java String concatenation with BaseColumns._ID brings an error

Tags: java, android, string-concatenation

In eclipse as soon as i type this out:

```
BaseColumns._ID, + "=?"
```

I get:

```
The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) String
```

How is that possible, they are both Strings aren't they?

now here is documentation for BaseColumns._ID:

```
public static final String _ID
```

the code I am writing is:

```
public void deteleProfile(Long id) throws SQLException {
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        Integer i = db.delete(ProlificDatabase.TABLE, BaseColumns._ID, + "=?", new String[] {id.toString()});
        Log.d(TAG, i + " records deleted where id is " + id);
```

Comment: doh, I feel really dim right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a rogue comma:

```
BaseColumns._ID, + "=?"
```

should probably be

```
BaseColumns._ID + "=?
```

Otherwise it's trying to use `+ "=?"` as a stand-alone argument with the `+` acting as a *unary* operator.

Comment: I hate when my commas go rogue.

Comment: @Kublai Khan: It's worse when they go rouge. That really makes me see red.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `BaseColumns._ID + "=?"` instead of `BaseColumns._ID, + "=?"`?

The compiler just sees the left hand side of the `+` operator as being empty.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) documentation on how to use the db.delete method. Instead of BaseColumns._ID, + "=?" - you should be doing this:

```
Integer i = db.delete(ProlificDatabase.TABLE, BaseColumns._ID + "=?", new String[] {id.toString()});
```

Answer (score 0):

Lovely extra `,` (comma)... love the commas for what they are, meaning a separator between expressions and a pain ... for when you overlook them!